# 90's PC game, similar to "Another World" but in 3D, dark, purple, locked inside a prison

Tags: story-identification, video-games

Back in late 1990s, after Internet but before CD-sized games being pirated over the Internet, I had a PC game which has been on my mind for a long time. It had a very graphically interesting opening sequence in many ways similar to the Amiga (and others) game *Another World* in terms of ambiance; the color palette being very dark with lots of dark blue and purple. You were not teleported to another world from Earth but rather in the future and space from the start, but ended up captured by either some alien race but humanoid shaped or other humans (your foes) but them wearing armor and visually distinguished from your appearance.

After the intro, you ended up in a prison cell and had to figure out how to escape. You were sitting down on a bench and you were the only occupant of the cell. In the middle of the screen and the center of the wall was a barred prison window and you could see things on the outside, possibly your foes/alien race working on this supposed military complex with prison. The prison door was most probably on the right side of the screen. I remember clearly that the only way I found was an air duct on the top of the left side of the screen which I was able to squeeze into. Once there, the scene changed to me crawling on my knees inside the duct. There is only one path but about halfway there is a spinning fan on the "floor" of the duct which shreds you to bits if you try to pass it. Your shredded intestines were of course purple and not red. I never made it past this second screen as I could not defeat the fan. It's possible the fan was never defeatable and that there was another way out from the cell in the first place.

There was a weapon-shaped object which the main character was somehow in possession of, but I was never able to fire it. It looked like an extremely low polygon count minigun; think 30 liter sized box for main body with one or two crude handles and a cylinder sticking out for a barrel. I was never able to fire it. Perhaps ammo was to be found later in the game? The weapon was disproportionally large compared to the main character.

Technically, it was pre-rendered or hand-drawn 3D environments with characters being low polygon 3D, very similar to *Alone in the Dark* but the backgrounds being far more reminiscent of *Another World* pixel style graphics and far less attempt-at-photo-realistic *Alone in the Dark*. The backgrounds would not move, it was just scene transitions from one room to the next, *Alone in the Dark* or *Resident Evil* style.

Despite having a Creative Sound Blaster and not a clone which would sometimes cause compatibility issues in the 90s era DOS games, I did not get sound and/or music working on this one. I was very computer savvy at the time so any DOS installer with manually setting up IRQ, DMA and such would not stop me, nor tweak any setup files manually or trying a lot of things to get around these kind of issues. I still never got it to work. It would for sure come with a DOS installer, but it may have been possible to run it under Windows. It was a bit too early in the "game" for crack groups to start stripping FMVs, compressing music and similar of CD-sized games for internet pirate distribution and music and sound being lost there.

The game most probably was keyboard controlled.

The game was very reminiscent of *Another World* in terms of color, style, prison, low-poly 3D (intro only of AW) and super interesting intro. I include some screenshots from Another world to get the color palette, but you need to mentally add more purple.

[image: Another world 1]

[image: Another world 2]

What was the game?

EDIT: 1995 BioForge did pop up after extensive searching. Intro with landing spaceship and waking up in a prison cell matches well as well as the 3D-character in 2D background type of gameplay, but visuals are way off.

EDIT2: I made a table of all your wonderful suggestions. Please let me know if I missed any.

[image: Table of suggestions]

More visual cues would perhaps be VirtuaVerse from 2020. The pixels are perhaps a little bit too large (it tries to look like SpaceQuest) for the presumed 640x480  resolution but color scheme and art style looks like something from the game.

[image: VirtuaVerse]
[image: More VirtuaVerse]

Comment: could it be [chronomaster](https://www.mobygames.com/game/dos/chronomaster)?

Comment: @AaronF That ticked a lot of boxes except not starting in a prison cell and being point and click instead of keyboard control.

Comment: You are looking for a PC game, but do you know if there was a console version (like Flashback or Another World)? That could help limit the scope of the search.

Comment: @Taladris Definitely not a console game. Would have been within the capabilities of the Playstation in the same way as Final Fantasy 7, but there was no keyboard on the Playstation and sound would have been working.

Comment: @winny Please consider if you might have mixed some details together from other games. What you describe as prison window scene fits 100% as part of prison path in Another World, see some middle screenshots at:  https://portforward.com/games/walkthroughs/Another-World/Jail.htm . And the part with  finding a duct to crawl through sounds like *another* different scene from AW. Or maybe that was from another game. I, too, remember something like that from one of the games listed in answers.

Comment: @Gnudiff It was not a platformer. There was no scene change by looking out the window. But if you take the image https://portforward.com/games/walkthroughs/Another-World/Another-World-small-17.jpg, move the camera to opposite of the barred window and pointing towards said window, remove the alien and make the room rectangular as opposed to dome and keep the polygon count of the character, it would be a very good start. Oh, and I never made it to the prison in Another world on my Amiga... The "snakes" would always kill me first. I was about 12 at the time.

Comment: Is it possible that you had a _demo version_ (or pre-release/bad crack/test version) of Alien Odyssey? It could explain a lower poly count and a different starting point. Could also explain not getting it to work correctly.

Comment: You *might* have had a badly configured version of one of those games. Very old DOS games could have an [EGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Graphics_Adapter) mode that would look very pink/purplish on VGA monitors. Some games had configurable palettes, but some were hard set.

Comment: Make that [CGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_Graphics_Adapter).

Comment: I've been through an exhaustive list of games featuring 3d rendered, static backgrounds similar to those discussed here via a few different games wiki sites and I've come up blank.  I did mostly ignore Japanese releases though - is the OP American/UK/? Did it have a rating? This may help in case it was some obscure demo or cover CD or something.

Comment: @user1971339 Sweden. Think UK or Germany and you are close enough. A bit too early for rating, which was a very American thing in the first place.

Comment: @RonanPaixão Sorry, no CGA. 640x480 in 256 colors.

Comment: @winny ta.  This is driving me nuts!  On the other hand I finally found the name of a game I've been wanting to replay from my childhood, just not the one you're looking for, so thanks (Hell: A Cyberpunk Thriller).  p.s. the kind of controls used in games like Bioforge are called 'tank controls' in case that helps.  i.e. relative to the screen position not the character.

Comment: If you have too much free time, you might consider going through this kind of list, although I can't guarantee the game is in there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_graphic_adventure_games

Answer (score 21):

I think I might have found it.

**Alien Odyssey**
(references: [#1](https://www.mobygames.com/game/dos/alien-odyssey/) [#2](https://collectionchamber.blogspot.com/2020/03/alien-odyssey.html))

[This screenshot from Moby Games](https://www.mobygames.com/game/dos/alien-odyssey/screenshots/gameShotId,236274/) depicts someone falling into a fan and purple blood:

[image]

The game doesn't start in a jail cell, but instead starts with an on-rails shooter sequence.

After the on-rails introduction and a cutscene, it switches to a fixed 3rd-person camera - like Alone in the Dark - and you have to infiltrate a base which is very purple in colour.

The large minigun-looking thing is something you find in the base and used to open doors.

Comment: Wow! An exceptionally good suggestion. If you ignore the initial FPS 3D rail shooter, the gameplay afterwards is fixed camera, jail cell and second screen is a gigantic fan. But it didn’t start with any Star Wars-esque speeder rail shooter. I should make a table of the suggestions.

Comment: @winny Maybe you played a demo that didn't include the on-rails shooter. Or you simply forgot that part for some reason... there aren't that many games of this style from that era, considering the effort it took to prerender 3D backgrounds and since each team usually coded its own new 3D engine...

Comment: @polynomial_donut I can't rule out that it was a demo, but the person being chopped by the fan looks like a cutscene and not an in-game event. The visuals also don't match.

Comment: @winny I have a very good memory myself but being wrong on information like sth. being in-game or a cutscene has also happened to me. Not trying to gaslight you, but with the graphics back then, nobody was able to credibly depict intestines coming out of anywhere unless prerendered... but yeah if the visuals don't match (cutscene or in-game, too?) that's something else. Now I'm super curious  P.s.: A [walkthrough](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/564500-alien-odyssey/faqs/1645) mentions shooting a fan. Maybe you didn't figure out how to shoot, so you couldn't pass it, another pro

Comment: @AaronF Just watched some more footage of Alien Odyssey. The fan scene was indeed an FMV cutscene but holy moly was there a lot of resemblance. The way he awkwardly held the minigun-shaped laser gun sort of off center of mass. But it's just too high polygon count, a bit too happy and not enough purple. Did the developers make a precursor to this one a year earlier with the which flopped because only I played it?

Comment: @polynomial_donut Your intestines being ground up by the fan was very low polygon. I'd say four or five blobs and not much animation going from a human into said blobs, more touch the fan blade and boom, purple blobs replacing the character and falling downwards. Given how many games from 1995 had more high polygon 3D characters and some full 3D environment, perhaps the game was even from 1994 or -93. But I didn't have my Pentium 166 until late 1995 or early 1996 and the game could have been a few years old by the time I played it.

Comment: Don't forget the slight chance that by now your nostalgia has slightly modified or even mashed up some memories of multiple games 

Comment: @Zommuter I can’t rule that out. I remember the Amiga game Flood having fantastic graphics, but when I loaded it up in the emulator, the 90’s nostalgia gloom became apparent. :-) But I do have very good memory otherwise. There can’t be that many games with tank control. If only there was a list I could search...

Comment: @winny If you're still looking for this game, take a look at [this review of Alien Odyssey](http://rememberpcdosgames.blogspot.com/2018/01/alien-odyssey-1995.html), especially the fan picture about halfway down.  It also confirms that AO has tank-style controls, and that the introductory shooter experience has very low actual gameplay - enough that you may have just forgotten that you did actually have to shoot a few things.  After reading that, it really ticks enough of your boxes that I can't imagine it being anything else.

Answer (score 15):

I think you're talking about *Fade to Black*.

The game begins in a prison cell:
[image]

It was created by Delphine Software, the same publishers as 'Another World'. It was a sequel to the 2D game 'Flashback' which, while not a direct sequel, was considered a spiritual successor to 'Another World' so it is not surprising you remember it having a similar feel.

[image]

Comment: Wow! An exceptionally good suggestion which fits almost every description. But Fade to black is first person shooter (or is there a term for when the camera is behind you?) and the game I’m after is fixed camera perspective per scene. Also, wayyy too little purple.

Comment: @winny It's called third person perspective

Comment: @Zommuter Yes, but when the camera position floats behind the character, as opposed to a fixed camera in space. Is there a specific name?

Comment: [Third-person shooter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_shooter)

Comment: @MarkRogers Excellent! What would be the technical term for fixed camera 3D adventure?

Comment: @winny "... many [point-and-click (graphic)] [adventure games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_game) use drawn or pre-rendered backgrounds, or a context-sensitive camera..."

Comment: @winny I'll keep this question in mind but do you think the retro computing site might be a better place to ask about this?

Comment: @Astralbee Could very well be. Do you have one in particular you would like to recommend?

Comment: @winny https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ is good and has a tag for 'identify this game'.

Comment: @Astralbee Excellent! Should this be migrated there?

Comment: @winny I'm not an admin, I wouldn't like to make that call. I was happy to answer it here (even though it was wrong) and you said you asked before posting so I'm not saying its off-topic. Might be worth enquiring with an admin?

Answer (score 15):

I believe Flashback is what you are looking for:

[image]

[image]

They also made a remake of Flashback. I've never played it and it doesn't seem to match up with the weapon you described. But there seems to be plenty of purple and prisons:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The cutscenes bears the same resemblance in art style as Another world, but Flashback is a platformer, not fixed camera 3D.

Comment: I was thinking of suggesting this - the intro sequence sounds right, and starting off in prison, but it's not 3D

Comment: @AaronF Imagine you could control the character in 3D in the bottom image, the cutscene of Flashback, and you are 98 % there.

Comment: Wait, what?! I thought Flashback and Anotherworld were the same game under different markets.

Comment: @DKNguyen nope. Similar, but different games. Another World was called Out Of This World in the US though.

Comment: @user25730 Oh yeah, I thought all those three were the same game too lol. 2/3 correctness rate. Still got it!

Answer (score 8):

[Little Big Adventure?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Big_Adventure)  It has several of the things you're talking about:

- The main character begins in an asylum/prison that must be escaped
- It is a science-fiction esque setting on a planet with two suns (named Twinsun, if that rings a bell)
- It's low-poly
- It plays like alone in the dark (it's a point-and-click ish adventure game I believe)
- No matter what I did I could never get it (or its sound) to work :-P

Comment: It's not isometrical overhead, but Alone in the dark 3D. The character gets bigger if you walk towards the "camera".

Comment: FWIW, there are emulated versions (for WIndows or Android) that run just fine. I owned copies of the game two decades ago and indeed, I couldn't get the sound to work for the first one at the time. It was an amazement to learn it was voice-acted.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've always wanted to actually play the game, but I could never get it to work.  I have no idea why, but it stuck in my head for probably more than 20 years as a game I wanted to play but couldn't.

Comment: https://www.gog.com/game/little_big_adventure might be a good option.

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible you were thinking of ***OnEscapee*** (pronounced 'one escapee', later re-released as *The Escapee*)? It's a sci-fi game in the vein of *Another World* and *Flashback* involving a rotoscoped character escaping from alien confinement.

[image]

Comment: Obscure! It’s definitely dark enough and has purple in the color palette, but it’s a platformer and not 3D.

Answer (score 4):

How about [BioForge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BioForge)? It was the first game I thought of when you mentioned being in a prison cell after the intro.

[image: bioforge-intro]

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgE0sZkw3Bs&list=PL1B94A2BEA4EF8465&index=2) video is part of a Let's Play series and shows the intro and escape scene.

Comment: Gameplay matches very good, but visuals are wayyy to happy, bright and not enough purple.

Answer (score 3):

I take it, it's not the actual sequel to *Another World* called *Heart of the Alien*, where you take on the role of the alien?

It was only released for the SEGA CD, but you can see it's Wikipedia entry here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_the_Alien

Comment: Any of the cinematic cutscenes are very close, but it was not a platformer and it was for sure on PC. Fast forward to 0:46 and it looks like the “next” scene what I can imagine from where I got stuck in the ventilation duct.